# Binding Converter with paramater in one line syntax

Tags: wpf, converters, ivalueconverter

I am basically trying to formulate the following Binding conditions in one line/tag:

```
<Rectangle.Fill>
     <Binding Path="Contents.Value">
          <Binding.Converter>
               <localVM:SquareConverter Empty="White" Filled="Black" Unknown="Gray"/>
           </Binding.Converter>
      </Binding>
</Rectangle.Fill>
```

I can't seem to figure out how to specify the parameters above `Empty="white" Filled="Black" Unkown="gray"`

What I have so far:

```
 <Button Background="{Binding Path=Contents.Value, Converter={StaticResource localVM:SquareConverter}, ConverterParameter={ }}">
```

I give it the resource fine I think, now I can't find out how to specify the parameters syntactically correct?

P.S. Don't worry about the context, the button background is mapped to a rectangle fill via control template etc.

Comment: Where do `Empty`,  `Filled` and `Unknown` properties come from? Is it a part of converter? make sense to share it in your question

Comment: You may declare the converer as resource and reference it by a StaticResource expression.  However, if you need a separate converter instance for each Binding, that wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski yes sorry, they are part of the converter so like if the value is Empty convert the background to white etc., but Clemens comment did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have noticed that the number of parameters that you can pass to Converter is just 1. You may pass an array of string or whatsoever, but I believe having all of your arguments in a single string would be easier to write and handle. For ex: `"Empty=White|Filled=Black|Unknown=Gray"`

Your converter should look like this:

```
public class SquareConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is string arg && parameter is string str)
        {
            string[] splits = str.Split("|"); // split by the delimiter
            var colorConverter = new ColorConverter(); // required to convert invariant string to color
            foreach (var kv in splits)
            {
                if(kv.StartsWith(arg, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    var v = kv.Split("=")[1]; // get the value from key-value
                    var color = (Color)colorConverter.ConvertFromInvariantString(v); // convert string to color
                    var brush = new SolidColorBrush(color); // convert color to solid color brush
                    return brush;
                }
            }
        }

        return default;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

in your xaml

```
xmlns:c="clr-namespace:WpfApp.Converters"

<Window.Resources>
    <c:SquareConverter x:Key="SquareConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Rectangle Fill="{Binding Path=Contents.Value,
                          Converter={StaticResource SquareConverter},
                          ConverterParameter='Empty=White|Filled=Black|Unknown=Gray'}"/>
```

Comment: oh ok this gives me more of an insight and broadens what i can do, thanks for your time